# how to make g++ cause an exception instead of warning on format mistake

Tags: c++, gcc

I need force gcc to raise an exception instead of warning on this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    printf ("Decimals: %d \n", 1977123124L);
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I running a cmd:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.o
```

test.cpp is a file with this code.

I wave a warning message in output:

```
test.cpp:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
```

and test.o file created.

What I want to have is error message and failed compilation.

Is there some flag or whatever to help gcc do this for me?

Thanks =)

Comment: You don't really mean "an exception", do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the switch `-Werror=format`.

More in general, whenever you have a warning that you want to turn into error, use `-Werror=(warning name)`; at the extreme, `-Werror` alone causes *all* warnings to turn into errors.